# Gson child object attributes return null

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to map a json to a data class in kotlin

JSON :

```
{
  "TimeZones": [
    {
      "MapZone": {
        "Other": "Afghanistan Standard Time",
        "Type": "Asia/Kabul",
        "Territory": "001"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

my data TimeZones.kt class

```
data class TimeZones (
        @Expose var TimeZones: List<MapZone>? = null
)

data class MapZone (
        @Expose var Other: String? = null,
        @Expose var Type: String? = null,
        @Expose var Territory: String? = null
)
```

but when I run this code the mapzone attribute values are always null

```
Gson().fromJson(Utils.readJSONFroRaw(), TimeZones::class.java)
```

I want to map this properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one level of the structure:

```
data class TimeZones (
        @Expose var TimeZones: List<TimeZone>? = null
)

data class TimeZone (
        @Expose var MapZone: MapZone? = null
)

data class MapZone (
        @Expose var Other: String? = null,
        @Expose var Type: String? = null,
        @Expose var Territory: String? = null
)
```